# Tkinter Treeview insertion rate

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, insertion, rate

I'm working on a Python app that reads messages from serial port, these messages are inserted in a treeview, I have a thread to manage the incoming messages, but I have a problem, with the insertion rate the tkinter GUI is stuck, if I comment the line to insert each message everything works well. Seems that treeview widget doesn't support that insertion rate. Do you know if there is a way to improve this without affect the incoming messages timestamp?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that new messages are inserted so often that the GUI freezes?

Comment: Yes, I have a thread to manage the incoming messages and the same thread inserts the data in the treeview

Comment: If you are modifying the content of the treeview from inside the thread then this is an issue since tkinter isn't thread-safe. So you should only modify the treeview (or any GUI element) from the main thread. You can try using a Queue for instance to communicate between your processes. I am sure there are examples on SO, most likely about Progressbar.